# Add operator arguments to console call

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I have an operator that I need to hand over arguments. I know that one possibility is to add attributes to the scene and use this but in `draw`-methods of operators I can modify the arguments passed to the operator directly. So I thought I should be able to do this from the console.

So far I have this operator (as an example):

```
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class ExampleOP(Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.test"
    bl_label = "Is just an example"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    foo = StringProperty()
    result = StringProperty()

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()

        col.prop_search(self, 'result', context.object.data, 'uv_textures', text="UV Layer")

    def execute(self, context):
        print(foo)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

What I want to do is `bpy.ops.object.test('INVOKE_DEFAULT', foo="something").`

**EDIT:** It seems to me that the answer only works for *Property()-objects not any object. This gives me a

> TpyeError: Convering py args to operator properties: keyword "ev" unrecognized

*Note: Please do not post any answers telling me off, to do this in another way. NO, this is exactly what I need, I cannot handle the "print-statement" outwards of the operator and yes, and foo may not always be a StringProperty.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already added [Operator Properties](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.props.html#operator-example) to your operator, which is perfectly fine.

The missing link is how to access the operator property values, which is rather simple (remember it's a python class after all):

```
print(self.foo)
```

`self` refers to the operator instance, which stores the property values.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class ExampleOP(Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.test"
    bl_label = "Is just an example"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    foo = StringProperty()
    result = StringProperty()

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()

        col.prop_search(self, 'result', context.object.data, 'uv_textures', text="UV Layer")

    def execute(self, context):
        print("foo =", self.foo)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.object.test('INVOKE_DEFAULT', foo="bar")
```

Comment: oh what a beginner error in my code... I am not sure why this wasn't a compiler error, after all there's no `gobal foo` declared... thanks again for pointing that out

Comment: this only seems to work for *Property-objects, not for any datastructure you may want to hand over

Comment: You only can - and should! - hand bpy.props types over. Not sure what you're trying, if you need a dynamically-sized list of basic types (string, int, float, bool...), use a CollectionProperty with a PropertyGroup of basic type equivalents. There shouldn't be a need to pass arbitrary data types. You can reference objects by name (=string) for instance, no need to pass by reference. In some rare cases, it can be necessary to store stuff in static members of a class (`class G: pass`, read and write anywhere in code: `G.global_var = 123`). Note that it will likely not have undo-capabilities.